# How to set the Environment variable from Launch4j

Tags: java, eclipse, sikuli, launch4j

I have create `java` application using `Sikuli-Script`. I added `2 new` `environment variable` from `Run Configuration`.

**Eclips Environment variable setting** 
[image]

After that i try to create Executable `.exe` file using `launch4j`.

How can i set the `Environment variable` from `Launch4j?`

**Launch4j set variable interface**
[image]

Comment: can somebody answer this, i would if i know how

Comment: @beNice launch4J not support for sikuli version 1.0.1. Please try exe4J(.EXE creating tool)

Answer (score 0):

You have to just specify your bin folder as below;

```
ADB=%EXEDIR%\\bin
Path=%Path%;%ADB%
```